# Predicting Classifications with Naive Bayes and dealing with Features/Words not in the training set

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, bayesian, supervised-learning, text-classification

Consider the text classification problem of spam or not spam with the Naive Bayes algorithm.

The question is the following:

how do you make predictions about a document W =  if in that set of words you see a new word wordX that was not seen at all by your model (so you do not even have a laplace smoothing probabilty estimated for it)?

Is the usual thing to do is just ignore that wordX eventhough it was seen in the current text because it has no probability associated with? I.e. I know sometimes the laplace smoothing is used to try to solve this problem, but what if that word is definitively new?

Some of the solutions that I've thought of:

1) Just ignore that words in estimating a classification (most simple, but sometimes wrong...?, however, if the training set is large enough, this is probably the best thing to do, as I think its reasonable to assume your features and stuff were selected well enough if you have say 1M or 20M data).

2) Add that word to your model and change your model completely, because the vocabulary changed so probabilities have to change everywhere (this does have a problem though since it could mean that you have to update the model frequently, specially if your analysis 1M documents, say)

I've done some research on this, read some of the Dan Jurafsky NLP and NB slides and watched some videos on coursera and looked through some research papers but I was not able to find something I found useful. It feels to me this problem is not new at all and there should be something (a heuristic..?) out there. If there isn't, it would be awesome to know that too!

Hope this is a useful post for the community and Thanks in advance.

PS: to make the issue a little more explicit with one of the solutions I've seen is, say that we see an unknown new word wordX in a spam, then for that word we can do 1/ count(spams) + |Vocabulary + 1|, the issue I have with doing something like that is that, then, does that mean we change the size of the vocabulary and now, every new document we classify, has a new feature and vocabulary word? This video seems to attempt to solve that issue but I'm not sure if either, thats a good thing to do or 2, maybe I have misunderstood it:

https://class.coursera.org/nlp/lecture/26

Answer (score 1):

From a practical perspective (keeping in mind this is not all you're asking), I'd suggest the following framework:

1. Train a model using an initial train set, and start using it for classificaion
2. Whenever a new word (with respect to your current model) appears, use some smoothing method to account for it. e.g. Laplace smoothing, as suggested in the question, might be a good start.
3. Periodically retrain your model using new data (usually in addition to the original train set), to account for changes in the problem domain, e.g. new terms. This can be done on preset intervals, e.g once a month; after some number of unknown words was encountered, or in an online manner, i.e. after each input document.

This retrain step can be done manually, e.g. collect all documents containing unknown terms, manually label them, and retrain; or using semi-supervised learning methods, e.g. automatically add the highest scored spam/ non spam documents to the respective models.

This will ensure your model stays updated and accounts for new terms - by adding them to the model from time to time, and by accounting for them even before that (simply ignoring them is usually not a good idea).